# Spring boot unit test how to load files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

everyone。When I was writing junit, I found that @ActiveProfiles corresponds to my resource directory。
I don’t understand how spring boot loads resource files,And why if I don’t specify @ActiveProfiles which application file is read by default?

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class NewTutorGroupIaoTest {
｝
```

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class NewTutorGroupIaoTest {
｝
```

project directory:

```
project 
- src 
    - main
        - java
        - resource
    - test
        - java
        - resource
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mark classes with `@Profile("test")`, you can ensure they're loaded (into the `ApplicationContext`) by activating the `test` profile - either with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`, `spring.profiles.active=test`, or a number of other ways. Classes can be excluded with `@Profile("!test")`

More details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles

Also, by activating a profile, you may also activate a properties file to be picked up... You may also have files in your project like:

- `application.properties`
- `application-default.properties`
- `application-test.properties`

If you have `application.properties` present as well as `application-test.properties`, `application.properties` forms the base config, and `application-test.properties` will overwrite any existing properties and may also supply additional configuration values.

If you supply/specify *no* profile, the `default` profile is activated.  This will result in `application.properties` + `application-default.properties` being combined (as before).

You will see in the logs which profile is activated very near the beginning of the Spring log output.

Comment: thanks! I was sick before, did not read the information, sorry. I saw the Profile  and ActiveProfiles of the  doc . And I also read the SpringBootTest source code, I understand the problem, thank you very much